# CosmosDbTrigger doesn't appear to be firing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I've got two sets of Azure Functions triggered by cosmos.

My local machine, with local cosmos, works and triggers fine, exactly when it should.

In the cloud, or on my (remote) dev machine, nothing appears to trigger.

I've used `StartFromBeginning` and deleted the leases collection, nothing happens - I only see this in the console.

[image: Remote Console]

However, on my local machine, triggering fine.

[image: Triggering fine]

My function looks like this:

```
[Function("Trigger")]
    public void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "db",
        collectionName: "col",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "connStr",
        CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
        StartFromBeginning = true,
        LeaseCollectionName = "leases")] IReadOnlyList<Entity> input)
    {
        if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Documents modified: " + input.Count);
            _logger.LogInformation("First document Id: " + input[0].Id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The screenshots are showing triggers on both. Your first screenshot shows the trigger fired due to an event on collection "checksumming":

[image]

Your second screenshot shows the Function fired due to new changes in the collection "hubs":

[image]

There is no evidence that the trigger is not firing.

In any case, one of the most common scenarios if you have 2 environments with the same code deployed (same monitored collection, same connection string, same lease collection name, one running in one environment and another in another environment) is that you should be using `LeaseCollectionPrefix` if you want multiple Functions to independently trigger on the same monitored collection when you share the lease collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-create-multiple-cosmos-db-triggers

Comment: Thanks. The "Hubs" is a completely different AZ account to the other.

Comment: They both fire, but only one actually 'fires' debugging the checksumming one, results in no function being actually started

Comment: I'll try your advice in the morning too, as that could be it!

Comment: I tore the whole thing back to nothing, no DI, no anything - it started working.  It's not a cosmos issue anymore - thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked, please remember to mark the answers so we know which questions are still open.

Comment: It's not the right answer, it worked for different reasons, DI was causing it :/ Would you suggest close? delete?

Comment: Add your answer and how you solved it as a new answer and mark it :)